# How to count occurrences in SQL without creating duplicates?

Tags: sql, performance, tags, count

I have a table of many movies all with associated with different Director IDs, I need to count the number of movies made by the same Director ID and what that Director's Name is.

My restrictions are to show only the Directors that have made 5 or more movies. I have 2 separate tables, One with the Movie names and Director IDs and one with the Director IDs and Director Names.

I have come up with the following query based on looking through other peoples answers on this website:

```
Select A.Director_name, C.cnt
from M_Movie B 
    Inner Join (select Director_ID, Director_Name
    from M_Director) A on B.Director_ID = A.Director_ID
        Inner Join (select Director_ID, count(Director_id) as cnt
        from M_Movie
        group by Director_ID) C on B.Director_ID = C.Director_ID
where cnt >= 5
order by cnt desc;
```

The above code delivers me the desired answer by listing the Director's Name and the number of movies they directed. - but **Heres the Problem...**

```
Director Name:       Number of Movies(CNT):

"Director A"           10
"Director A"           10
"Director A"           10
"Director A"           10... (Happens 10 Times)
"Director B"           8
"Director B"           8
"Director B"           8.... (Happens 8 Times)
"Director C"           7
```

The answer lists "Director A" (who directed 10 movies) 10 times with the "CNT" as 10, and then next in the list is "Director B" (who directed 8 movies) 8 times with the "CNT" as 8, and then "Director C" is listed 7 times and so on...

I would ideally like to have:

```
Director Name:       Number of Movies(CNT):

"Director A"           10
"Director B"           8
"Director C"           7
```

With no repeats, just the listed names of the Directors and the Number of Movies they Directed.

PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is to add a `DISTINCT` to your query

```
Select DISTINCT A.Director_name, C.cnt
```

However, you could probably rewrite your query to avoid that.
Something like...

```
Select A.Director_name, count(B.MovieID)
from M_Movie B 
    Inner Join 
    M_Director A 
        on B.Director_ID = A.Director_ID
group by a.Director_Name
having count(b.MovieID) >=5 
order by count(b.MovieID)  desc;
```

Comment: How would I join on a third table? 
If say I wanted to change "Director_name" to "Director_First_name" that was in a table called  M_DireIncred? (this table holds "Director_name", "Director_First_name", "Director_Last_name", ""Director_Age")

Comment: just carry on joining ... `INNER JOIN M_DireIncred on a.Director_Name = M_direIncred.Director_Name`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT Director_Name, COUNT(*) as [Count]
FROM M_Movie m
JOIN M_Director d on m.Director_ID = d.Director_ID
GROUP BY Director_Name
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 5
```

The `HAVING` runs after the grouping, hence you can use it to filter the number of records.

Answer (score 0):

So you have basically two options: to use the `DISTINCT` keyword or to `GROUP BY` Director_name with `HAVING COUNT(*)`.
The `DISTINCT` keyword specifies removal of duplicate rows from the result set. 
The end result will be the same, but the performance is better when use `GROUP BY` instead of `DISTINCT`.

Comment: DISTINCT would be better in case you have an index on Director_name.